# jQuery receiving value from a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

My *HTML* :

```
<div class="textForm">
<input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="10" checked="checked" />10
<input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="20" />20
<input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="other" />other
<input type="text" name="other_field" id="other_field" onblur="checktext(this);"/>
</div>
<div class="formText">
<input type="radio" name="txtSpace" value="RJ" checked="checked"
/>Space 1.
<br />
<input type="radio" name="txtSpace" value="SM" />Space 2.
<br />
</div>
<h3>Output:</h3>
<div id="output"></div>
```

This is my *javascript* code

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
$("input[name='txtNumber'],input[name='txtSpace']").change(function () 
{
    console.log("changed");
    if ($("input[name='txtSpace']:checked").val() == 'RJ' && $("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '10')
        $("#output").text("RJ, 10 = 20");
    else if ($("input[name='txtSpace']:checked").val() == 'RJ' && $("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '20')
        $("#output").text("RJ, 20 = 40");
    else if ($("input[name='txtSpace']:checked").val() == 'RJ' && $("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == 'other') // HERE I M CONFUSED
WHAT SHALL BE THE CODE?
    else if ($("input[name='txtSpace']:checked").val() == 'SM' && $("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '10')
        $("#output").text("SM, 10 = 5");
    else if ($("input[name='txtSpace']:checked").val() == 'SM' && $("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '20')
        $("#output").text("SM, 20 = 10");
    else if ($("input[name='txtSpace']:checked").val() == 'SM' && $("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == 'other') // HERE AGAIN I M CONFUSED
        $("#output").text("SM , ???? = Dont know");
});
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to open up the "other_fields" on clicking the "other" radio button the "other_field". Now, I want to use the value from "other_field" (i.e. the user input) and use those numbers in my calculation.

Comment: You should really set the `val()` to a variable. You'd see a massive performance increase with that many duplicated selectors

Comment: There is another way to make your if and else statement simple

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as you can see that i m learning much in scripting and all i learn is cuz of friends like you so if you can show how i can achieve it.. i ll be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of the `other_field` by using

```
    var textVal = $('#other_field').val();
    console.log(textVal)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$("#other_field").val()` to select the value of the other input field.

```
else if ($("input[name='txtSpace']:checked").val() == 'RJ' &&
    $("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == 'other')  {
        var val = parseInt($("#other_field").val(), 10);
        $("#output").text("RJ , " + val " = " + (val * 2));
}
...
else if ($("input[name='txtSpace']:checked").val() == 'SM' &&
    $("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == 'other') {
        var val = parseInt($("#other_field").val(), 10);
        $("#output").text("SM , " + val " = " + (val / 2));
}
```

Comment: `parseInt('08')` returns 0.  The `10` forces it to be converted to a radix 10 (decimal) number

Comment: It's the radix parameter, used to indicate that the string value should be converted to a base10 integer.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Raja used this command.. var textVal = $('#other_field').val(); Almost same as you showed.. Adding parseInt adds what functionality?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan also what is the use of console.log(textVal) in relation to this.. I know console posts the value to jquery console.. But what is the benefit of posting these values??

Comment: There is no special benefit. It just prints the value to the console. I added it, so that you can verify whether you are getting the expected value from textVal.

Comment: @Ashis `parseInt` just makes sure that the correct integer value is acquired and as an integer.  If you use `+` with a string, it will concatenate incorrectly